# Alternate of DCEVM for HOt Reload

Tags: java

As i came to know about DCEVM which supports hot reloading in the java application i am working with the jre_1.8.0_352 but the DCEVM latest release for the java 8 is 1.8.0_181.Is there any alternate tool for Hot reload in java applications that comes with commercial license.I also know about jrebel but it comes with the comercial license.Can anyone suggest me with the open source tools.

already using DCEVM need another tool.

Comment: Seems out of topic